# Match word but not question mark

Tags: pandoc

I have this Lua filter:

```
return {
    {
        Str = function (elem)
        if elem.text == "Dog" then
            return {pandoc.Str "Cat"}
        else
            return elem
        end
        end,
    }
}
```

which works fine on something like:

```
This is a Dog
```

but not on

```
This is a Dog?
```

Having glanced at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204136/to-regex-pandoc-tables this seems a very complicated job to do.

Is there a simple solution for a pandoc beginner?

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that should work in most cases. It first splits the text into alphanumeric characters and punctuation, then checks the word, and re-appends the punctuation if necessary:

```lua
function Str (str)
  local word, punct = str.text:match '(%w*)(%p*)'
  if word == 'Dog' then
    return 'Cat' .. punct
  end
end
```

Lua doesn't use regex, but a simpler pattern matcher described [in the manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1). (You could use regex in pandoc via `re`, but that's a different story.)